# Emacs 24.3 case sensitive search fails with C-s C-s "search again"

Tags: search, emacs, case-sensitive

My problem is this:

- Set `case-fold-search` to `t` (case insensitive).
- <kbd>C-s</kbd> `thisisaverylongword` (search for a string).
- Emacs finds `ThisIsAVeryLongWord` (correct).
- Exit incremental search.
- Set `case-fold-search` to `nil` (case sensitive).
- <kbd>C-s</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> (search again for previous string).
- Emacs still finds `ThisIsAVeryLongWord` (**wrong**).

To let `case-fold-search` work properly, I must retype a new command.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you know about `M-s c` (`isearch-toggle-case-fold`)?

Comment: I did reproduce this behaviour on Emacs 24.3.1 and 24.3.50 using -q. A workaround is to use `C-s M-p C-s` to get to the search history instead of `C-s C-s` which reuses `isearch-last-case-fold-search` and gives the unexpected behaviour (after inspecting source for `isearch-repeat`).

Comment: @Juancho: I cannot repro this behavior on *any& Emacs release, from 20 through 24 (including recent dev snapshots).  See my answer posted below.  Do you really see a different behavior from that?  (This is about option `case-fold-search`, not internal variable `isearch-case-fold-search`.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see now that the OP asked about `C-s C-s`.  Yes, that picks up the previous search as it was.  But it is sufficient to use `M-e` followed by `C-s`, to reuse the previous string and yet respect the new value of the option.

Comment: Always worth a mention: `C-s C-h b` will show you all the bindings available when `isearch`ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not what happens for me.  Please provide a clear recipe from `emacs -Q`.

Here's what I see:

```
emacs -Q
M-x set-variable RET case-fold-search RET t RET
C-s ; searches insensitively
M-x set-variable RET case-fold-search RET nil RET
C-s ; searches sensitively
```

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I missed that you were simply using <kbd>C-s</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd>.  That reuses not only the same search string but the same search state.  Just use <kbd>M-e</kbd>, to "edit" the last search string, and make no change to it (just hit <kbd>C-s</kbd> again).  That will pick up the latest value of `case-fold-search`.

IOW:

```
emacs -Q
M-x set-variable RET case-fold-search RET t RET
C-s ; searches insensitively
M-x set-variable RET case-fold-search RET nil RET
C-s M-e C-s  ; searches last search string sensitively
```

---

(*Ignore this if you are already confused and don't want to risk further confusion.* ;-)  If not, it might help.)

If you use library [**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/IsearchPlus) then you have a choice w/r/t how Boolean options are handled.

With vanilla Isearch, any on-the-fly toggling affects only the current Isearch invocation (i.e., exiting Isearch and starting it again reverts to the behavior of the saved option value, whatever that might be).

With **Isearch+**, Boolean option **`isearchp-toggle-option-flag`** controls whether commands that toggle behavior also toggle the associated user option. For such commands, a prefix argument flips the behavior, as if `isearchp-toggle-option-flag` were toggled temporarily. Currently this feature applies to the toggles <kbd>M-c</kbd> (case-sensitivity) and <kbd>M-s i</kbd> (matching hidden text).

You can toggle option `isearchp-toggle-option-flag` itself during Isearch, with <kbd>M-s v</kbd>.

Comment: Also starting with -Q the problem persist. I will add  screen shot.

Comment: C-s C-e C-s is what I was looking for. I use this in function, and I need the capability to change behavior, so your suggestion about isearch+ is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't ever manually change the `case-fold-search` variable. Here is how I handle case sensitive and insensitive searching:

- <kbd>C-s</kbd> `thisisaverylongword`

  - This is case-insensitive by default, so it finds `ThisIsAVeryLongWord` (correct)
- <kbd>RET</kbd> to exit `isearch`
- <kbd>C-s</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> to search for the same word again (at this point it's still case-insensitive)
- <kbd>M-c</kbd> **to toggle case-sensitivity for the active search**

  - Now `ThisIsAVeryLongWord` does not match (correct)
  - <kbd>M-c</kbd> calls `isearch-toggle-case-fold`, the same function identified by [abo-abo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350992/abo-abo) [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687635/emacs-24-3-case-sensitive-search-fails-with-c-s-c-s-search-again/22690421#comment34568362_22687635)

Comment: Same here (and one need not exit Isearch).  But that does not answer the question posed.  The question is about lack of respect of option `case-fold-search`, not just about how to change case-sensitivity during Isearch.  @abo-abo's comment is an appropriate and helpful reminder, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Drew, exiting `isearch` is merely included to show how this behaviour operates with `C-s C-s` (as in the question), but of course you are correct that it is not necessary. Although the question *asks about* manually modifying variables, it sounds to me like an XY problem and the actual question is about toggling case-sensitivity in `isearch`. Perhaps I am mistaken. The only person who can answer that is the OP. I think I'll leave this here for the time being.

Comment: I agree that the question posed might not be the real question. And all of the info provided in comments and answers is helpful. And yes, this can be confusing.